# How to get the products by categories in woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to get all the products by categories to create a menu.

The output should be like:

```
    name of category1
      product in category1
      product in category1
      product in category1
   name of  category2
      product in category2
      product in category2
      product in category2
```

For this I am using this code:

```
<?php
                    $args = array(
                        'number' => $number,
                        'orderby' => $orderby,
                        'order' => $order,
                        'hide_empty' => $hide_empty,
                        'include' => $ids
                    );

                    $product_categories = get_terms('product_cat', $args);

                    ?>
```

But do not how to get the result printed in that format mentioned above.

I am new to woocommerce and wordpress. Please help me.

Comment: You can do that by iterating categories and get products under specific category. See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24883682/how-to-get-the-products-by-categories-in-woocommerce/24884023#24884023) for more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by iterating categories you already fetched and list product under each categories like;

```
$args = array(
    'number' => $number,
    'orderby' => $orderby,
    'order' => $order,
    'hide_empty' => $hide_empty,
    'include' => $ids
);

$product_categories = get_terms('product_cat', $args);
?>
<ul>
    <?php
        foreach ($product_categories as $cat) {
            ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php echo get_term_link($cat->slug, 'product_cat'); ?>"><?php echo $cat->name;?></a>
                    <ul>
                        <?php
                        $productArgs = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'product_cat' => $cat->name, 'orderby' => 'rand' );
                        $products = new WP_Query( $productArgs );
                        while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post(); global $product; ?>

                            <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $products->post->ID ) ?>"><?php echo $products->post->title;?></a></li>

                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                    </ul>
                </li>

    <?php 
        }

    wp_reset_query(); ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: I have used this code but it is showing error link {Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in line woocommerce.php 99}

Comment: @user3777827 there was a spell mistake. You can use updated code now

Comment: printing only categories not their products . You can view the output here:{http://dev.kcseocompany.com/dagmar-new/product-category/pop-up-tents/} in the left sidebar

Comment: @user3777827 I have updated `$cat->slug` to `$cat->name`. Could you please update your code as well?

Comment: How can I echo product name under categories now they are comming in link which is not visible and is visible only under inspect element.